# How to tell MySQL which table to search first

Tags: mysql

MySQL is searching the tables in incorrect order.

I have this

```
SELECT *
FROM trx 
   inner join mst on (mst.pk = trx.fk)
WHERE trx.locid = 'xx'
```

This query is long, because MySQL is searching the table `mst` first before cross referencing with `trx`, instead of the other way around.

```
During EXPLAIN, the result is 
SIMPLE mst
SIMPLE trx
(in that order)

I need this 
SIMPLE trx
SIMPLE mst 
(trx first, before mst)
```

This is weird, because all my other SQL statements are doing fine, except for this one.

Can we tell MySQL to filter which table first, and then reference the other table next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible explanation for why MySQL is scanning `mst` before `trx`, despite that these two tables appear in the opposite order in the query, is that the order of tables does not matter for an `INNER JOIN`.  For whatever reason, the query optimizer must think it would be faster to join this way.

Primary key columns in MySQL are implicitly indexed, for both MyISAM and InnoDB.  So I don't think the `mst.pk` column is a problem here.  But the `trx.fk` column might benefit from an index.  To test this hypothesis, you can add an index on that column if you have not already done so:

```
ALTER TABLE trx ADD INDEX `fk_idx` (fk)
```

With both join columns indexed, the order of joining should not make much difference and hopefully you will have the performance you need.

Comment: Did that, and it actually helped speed up things.  But the query optimizer still look at mst before trx.  Weird.  First time to encounter this.

Comment: As I mentioned, logically there is no difference with regard to the order of tables in an inner join, because only records common between the two (i.e. the ones overlapping based on a condition) are retained.  So, this order does not change your result set.  Yes, I've never seen this before, but I'll keep it in mind for later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.

Found that `USE INDEX` helps in this case.

```
SELECT *
FROM trx USE INDEX(index_name)
   inner join mst USE INDEX(PRIMARY) on (mst.pk = trx.fk)
WHERE trx.locid = 'xx'
```